# Need help figuring out which direction to implement Structure Map for an MVC 3 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have been reading a number of tutorials on implementing Structure Map IoC/di into a MVC 3 project.  Only to get to the comments on the article and find what appears to be less favorable methods being used in the article either because they didn't use the scanning capabilities of Structure Map, or because they are using an Activator class when its not needed or not encapsulating the registration from the application and the list goes on.

I have a MVC 3 application that "currently" only uses DI for wiring up a NHibernate, its session in a unit of work, and injecting my controllers with a repository.  However, I want to switch over to Structure Map (since that is what is used at work and I want the experience) but I want to implement it with the direction that I have the most flexibility to use Structure Map with Filters, Model Binders...etc as well.

Does anyone have a good walk through for this recommendation they can point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2011/1/20/structuremap-and-asp-net-mvc-3-getting-started) is a pretty good walkthrough.

Comment: Actually, this is one of the ones I was referring to based on a number of deficiencies in the way he was implementing Structure Map pointed out in the comments.

Comment: The reason he didn't use all the features of SM is so that the article doesnt get bogged down in SM detail. The series is on using SM within MVC 3. He explains that in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I understand hes reasons, and yes, I read that in the comments, but that still doesn't detract from the fact that if he is not implementing the structure or features I am looking for, then how is it useful to what I am trying to accomplish.